# Trigerring Axios calls after a day/week/month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I have functions in my react project that fire a axios call to change a users membershipType to daily, weekly or monthly in the database. They then have to manually be changed back to expired. Is there any way I can have a "timer" function to trigger another axios call to automatically change it back to Expired after a day, week or month? Or is there a better way to go about doing this? This approach seems a little messy

Comment: I think this task can be done from your backend, because frontend like `react` need to be opened if you want to trigger method in some interval. If you use Cpanel, you can use cron job to call spesific method on some interval time

Answer (score 1):

You should use a cron to do that.

Register in the database the end of the period for the membership as expiration_time, and have a cron run every day/month/whatever time you think is necessary.

This cron would update all the rows with a expiration_time inferior to the current date, and set their status to expired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cloud service to do this (for free I believe). I would configure a [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function that's triggered by a [CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html) event. The Cloudwatch event can be a Cron expression that will invoke the Lambda on a given schedule.

Your Cron expressions would be as follows:

```
0 0 0 * * ?   // Every Day at Midnight
0 0 0 */7 * ? // Every 7 Days at Midnight
0 0 0 1L * ?  // Last Sunday of the Month at Midnight
```

More on Cron expressions [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)